# useEffect clean up not working on iOS app kill in React Native

Tags: react-native, use-effect, google-cast, react-native-google-cast

I am trying to call a stop casting function in useEffect clean up function but it is not being called when the app is killed. How can I call a function that will work when app is killed?

P.S. this works on android

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      // Not being called on iOS
      sessionManager?.endCurrentSession && sessionManager?.endCurrentSession(true);
    };
  }, []);
```